# Grails: CookieTheftException with anonymous access

Tags: session, grails, cookies

I have a grails server and an iOS client that communicate over HTTPS via POST messages. I'm using PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices to ensure that the user doesn't have to enter his password all the time. This doesn't seem to work as the session is lost continuously and the user has to login again. The server logs show that a CookieTheftException has occurred with message "Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch".

Not all server actions require a logged in user. Some can be accessed anonymously and this may be the root of the problem. When the user accesses restricted server actions, the session is maintained, but not when accessing unrestricted actions.

Here's my config in Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.cookieName = 'SomeRememberMeName'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.alwaysRemember = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistentToken.domainClassName = 'com.myapp.PersistentLogin'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds=31*24*60*60
```

I added some traces in the iOS client and noticed a couple of things. First of all the JSESSIONID cookie doesn't have an expiration time, which means it isn't saved in the client like the rememberMe cookie. Can I force it to have an expiration time or is that even a good idea? Secondly I noticed that sometimes the rememberMe cookie that I receive from the server is empty. That may be just because a CookieTheftException was thrown.

Since all of the post message bodies are encrypted with 256-bit AES, I'm not really worried about cookie theft at this time. I just need to get this to work.

I tried adding the following to my config to ensure that the session would be always updated even when accessing unrestricted actions:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.SessionFixationPrevention.migrate = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.SessionFixationPrevention.alwaysCreateSession = true
```

I don't even know what these all mean. I just liked the "alwaysCreateSession" part and figured that I need to enable session fixation prevention in order for that setting to have any effect. Will it still always create a session if I set useSessionFixationPrevention to false?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`, your "remember me" token will change after every HTTP request.

Unfortunately that means that requests will only authenticate if your browser makes exactly one request at a time, and browsers often don't do that.  If there are 4 few images on a page, the browser will send out 4 simultaneous requests, each with the same "remember me" token. Only the first request will authenticate, because after Spring Security processes the first request, it changes the token.  When Spring Security tries to process the next request, it throws a `CookieTheftException`.

That's the typical scenerio for the `CookieTheftException` when using `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`.

Here's a link that explains some things you can do about it: [Grails Cookie Theft Exceptions](http://www.cloudseal.com/2013/03/grails-cookie-theft-exceptions/)

There's also an open issue with the Grails Spring Security Core plugin that discusses this problem: [Remember me functionality fails intermittently with CookieTheftException: Invalid remember-me token](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-70)

The JSESSIONID stuff is probably a red herring. If you're using `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`, your authentication won't need a session.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had read that site you posted but I was hesitant to do what it suggested because it seemed too hacky and unsafe to me. But after several failed attempts at fixing this some other way I ended up doing exactly that. Now that the cookie is never updated the CookieTheftException has gone away. Disabling a security feature this way still bothers me though.